# Converting a xUnit test case using MemberData to nUnit

Tags: nunit, xunit

Let's say I have the following test case that has been written using xUnit:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> testValues = new List<object[]>
{
    new object[] {new double?[] {0.0}, 0.0, 0.0},
};

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(testValues))]
public void Test1(double?[] values, double expectedQ1, double expectedQ3)
{
    // Test code
}
```

How could I express the same unit test in nUnit instead of xUnit?

Note: The main problem here seems to be the use of MemberData, which for so far, I haven't been able to find an nUnit equivalent. What would be the correct way of expressing such unit test cases in nUnit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> testValues = new List<object[]>
{
    new object[] {new double?[] {0.0}, 0.0, 0.0},
};

[TestCaseSource(nameof(testValues))]
public void Test1(double?[] values, double expectedQ1, double expectedQ3)
{
    // Test code
}
```

Note that NUnit has `TheoryAttribute` but you don't want it here. In NUnit, a Theory is a bit more than just a parameterized test. You should read the docs to understand what it is before deciding if you need it. Of course, you should read up on `TestCaseSourceAttribute` as well. :-)

Other attributes in NUnit that allow data to be specified for a test case include `TestCaseAttribute`, `ValuesAttribute`, `ValueSourceAttribute`, `RandomAttribute` and `RangeAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! TestCaseSource was what I was looking for.